# Remove line breaks from pasted text in Spark TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, tlf

I'm trying to remove all line breaks from the text that is pasted into the Spark TextArea.

I have:
`<s:TextArea id="inputSearchQuery"
    width="100%" height="22"
    minHeight="22" maxHeight="196"
    changing="onInputSearchQueryChanging(event)"/>`

And handler:

```
private function onInputSearchQueryChanging(evt:TextOperationEvent = null):void {
    if (evt.operation is PasteOperation) {

    }
}
```

Where can I find a text that user pasted? As I understand, this text should be in evt.operation.textFlow but it is not... I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasted text is in `(evt.operation as PasteOperation).textScrap`. So you can extract text from `textScrap.textFlow`.

Comment: Hmmm... Using tlf_internal namespace? This is not a hack? Is not there a simpler way?

Comment: This namespace isn't hack. It is just for advanced use. You can use it without any problem.

Comment: Thnx! So, for removing line breaks I need to alternate (evt.operation as PasteOperation).textScrap.textFlow and do not preventing evt? I'm trying this: `var tf:TextFlow   = (evt.operation as PasteOperation).textScrap.textFlow;
     var p:ParagraphElement = new ParagraphElement();
     var span:SpanElement = new SpanElement();
     var t:String   = tf.getText();
     span.text    = t.replace(/\n/ig, "");
     p.addChild(span);
     tf.replaceChildren(0, tf.numChildren, p);` But get exception (